# Is it possible for a web-based application to somehow access a smartphone's location ? And report back?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-maps-api-3

My web application is built in Flask (DIY web framework for Python) and I would like to include my user's location on a map with our other assets.

I have not built applications on either android or iPhone. I am unclear as to the scope of this task.

stack: `CentOS6`, `Python`, `Flask`, `Twilio`, and anything the user's browser is capable of (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with HTML5 comes the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I'll accept it when it lets me. Any idea how "expensive" this is in terms of the user's data or battery? Every five minutes? 5 seconds?

Comment: This happens when the page loads. It will not *track* your user. If you need to query the location at an interval, you need to set that up by yourself.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, yes i was planning on implementing a "ping interval"  but i dont know what kinds of costs to the user's hardware i am dealing with

Comment: Well I don't know either and this will depend on the mobile device type and other factors. Geolocation can use the GPS chip (if present and available), or wireless networks proximity (again if a wifi chip is present and available), or mobile repeaters triangulation. That's what I know about it. So of course, the *cost to the user's hardware* will depend on what technique is available and used.